# No viable conversion from Singleton to nested Listener *

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton, listener

Couldn't find the solution elsewhere on site but please point me elsewhere incase I'm wrong.

Say I wanted to listen to a button and do something depending on its size from a singleton object...

I would create a button object with a nested listener...

```
class ScaledButton
{
public:
    ScaledButton(const int buttonSize) : _buttonSize(buttonSize){}

    ~ScaledButton(){}

    /** Nested Listener calss*/
    class Listener
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Listener() {}

        /** Would be called on button click for example... */
        virtual void scaledButtonChanged(const int buttonSize) = 0;
    };

    void addListener (Listener* listener)
    {
        _listener = listener;
    }

private:
    ScaledButton();
    int _buttonSize;
    Listener* _listener; ///< POINTER TO THE LISTENER
};
```

Then create my singleton that inherits publicly from the listener...

```
class Singleton : public ScaledButton::Listener ///< PUBLIC INHERITANCE HERE
{
public:
    static Singleton& getInstance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    virtual void scaledButtonChanged(const int buttonSize) override
    {
        //... do something depending on the size of the button!!!!!!
    }

private:
    Singleton(){} // Must call get instance.
    Singleton(const Singleton&); // Cannot copy
    void operator= (const Singleton& args); // Cannot copy
};
```

And within main add the listener like so..

```
int main()
{
    Singleton& mySingleton = Singleton::getInstance();

    ScaledButton myButton(5);
    myButton.addListener(mySingleton); ///< ERROR HERE!

    return 0;
}
```

However the listener cannot be added with the error:

*No viable conversion from 'Singleton' to 'ScaledButton::Listener *'*

My hunch is that it is to do with the conflict of using a singleton with a reference and Listener with a pointer: or the inheritance of the pure virtual Listener class.

My C++ skills aren't quite sharp enough to solve the error despite trying various singleton implementations (such as using a global ptr). Any suggestions?

On Mac OS using a clang compiler.

Comment: You should pay attention to differences between pointer / reference types

Comment: `myButton.addListener(mySingleton);` -> `myButton.addListener(&mySingleton);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a pointer, so take the address of your object:

```
myButton.addListener(&mySingleton);
```

If you have background in other languages, you need read more about reference vs value semantics in C++.